# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'baseUrl' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting

I have a Polymer webapp deployed using Firebase hosting.

The routing between views works but the error page handling is not.

I have succeeded to reproduce the issue on a minimal example using the official *polymer-2-starter-kit* example:

https://fir-polymer-404-issue.firebaseapp.com/

For instance, if you open the following URL, the error page is not displayed:

https://fir-polymer-404-issue.firebaseapp.com/not-existing

Instead, I get the error below:

```
my-not-existing.html:56 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'baseUrl' has already been declared
    at my-not-existing.html:56
(anonymous) @   my-not-existing.html:56
```

The configuration file *firebase.json* used for the previous example is here:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to have the error page handling made by Polymer.

Please note that the same app served by `polymer serve` works properly.

It seems the problem comes from the Firebase hosting configuration. All traffic is redirected to index.html so when Polymer load a not-existing page, the Firebase server returns an HTTP 200 response. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix the problem.

I have tried to create a redirection for non-404 responses only with the following configuration file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".",
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html",
        "type": 200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the *type* property can be used for 3xx code only:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.redirects[0].type is not one of enum values: 301,302,303,304,305,307,308
```

Please also note that a custom *404.html* file is [placed at the root](https://fir-polymer-404-issue.firebaseapp.com/404.html).

The only solution I see is to list all existing routes (per file) but it looks just crazy.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: I saw a 304 on the non existing url. did you updated it?

Comment: No, the configuration file _firebase.json_ has not been touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason neither firebase or polymer is going to handle your `404` page is that when you request a non-existing page, it's not only going to return with the status code `200` but it's also going to return with the HTML of the `index` page, so it will display something, although that something is really nothing.

Now the way polymer is set up it looks for views in the `src` folder, so you want a rewrite just on the root and not in the `src` folder. So change your `firebase.json` to be

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": ".",
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "/*",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

The single `*` will mean files but not subfolders, this will allow your routeing to work if you enter it in the address bar but if the page is not found the `404` will be handled by polymers routeing. I've set up a firebase application using the polymer starter pack to for an example.

https://testforsoissue.firebaseapp.com/view2

Will work and will take you to `view2` as the initial request will be rewritten to return index.html but the request for `/src/my-view2.html` will not

Whereas a route that is not defined

https://testforsoissue.firebaseapp.com/not-existing

Will throw a 404 (in polymer) as the initial request will again be rewritten to return `index.html` but the request for `/src/my-not-existing.html` will not and will happily throw a 404!

P.S. the reason for the error `'baseUrl' has already been declared'` is due to the fact the page was using the index.html twice which declares the baseUrl at the top

**Edit**

If you have subpaths seems like you can use the `firebase.json` like so

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": ".",
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "!/src/*",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, what happens if the URL contains subpaths such as `https://testforsoissue.firebaseapp.com/view2/myId`. In that case, it seems that Polymer will no longer be able to handle the request since the redirection to index.html is not set for subpaths. In a real app scenario, such as the one I am trying to build, it is an issue.

Answer (score -1):

As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites), you do not need to do the handling; just create a 404.html:

> You can specify a custom 404/Not Found error to be served when a user tries to access a page that does not exist. Simply add a 404.html page to the your project's public directory and the contents of this page will be displayed when Firebase Hosting needs to display a 404 Not Found error to the user.

---

To avoid the baseUrl error, if you have access to this line of code:

`let baseUrl = document.querySelector('base').href;`

Try changing it for:

`baseUrl = baseUrl || document.querySelector('base').href;`

It's not very neat, but it should not complain about the value being defined already.

Although I think this is unrelated to your problem and may stop showing this error once a proper 404 page is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the project by following your 2 suggestions but, as you can see, none helps. Unfortunately, the custom [error page](https://fir-polymer-404-issue.firebaseapp.com/404.html) is not returned when the default rewrites to _index.html_ are in place and this last is a requirement for using Polymer with slash-separated paths.